# OpenSSL internal error, assertion failed: FATAL FIPS SELFTEST FAILURE

Tags: python, linux, openssl, fips

I had an application written in Python3.9 packaged as executable file using PyInstaller in a CentOs7 docker image. Able to install the app successfully in linux machines where FIPS is disabled.

If I try install it in FIPS enabled RHEL8.7 machine it gives the below error

```
fips.c(145): OpenSSL internal error, assertion failed: FATAL FIPS SELFTEST FAILURE
```

Then after a bit of research, thought the issue could be due to building the application in a FIPS disabled docker image. So tried to enable FIPS in the docker image and then built the application.

With OpenSSL v1.0.2t and openssl-fips v2.0.16, the app executable file works fine in both FIPS enabled as well as FIPS disabled RHEL8.7 linux machine.

But as OpenSSL v1.0.2 EOLed, tried to use Openssl-3.1.0 with FIPS enabled and built the application. It works fine if FIPS disabled, but gives the same error if FIPS enabled.

```
fips.c(145): OpenSSL internal error, assertion failed: FATAL FIPS SELFTEST FAILURE
```

The RHEL8.7 machine which I am using to test the application has Openssl `OpenSSL 1.1.1k  FIPS 25 Mar 2021` version.

If I build the app in the same RHEL machine it works fine, but not if built with Openssl 3.1.0 FIPS enabled in a CentOs7 image.

Any ideas, suggestions on how to resolve this issue, thanks.